# Overlapping intervals in PostgreSQL based on week days

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table `alert_conditions`. It represents `AlertCondition` entity, from business logic perspective a user can create the record so under some circumstances there is an alert that notifies the user that something is out of order.

To simplify things, the record has the following properties:

- `day_of_week` - from 0 to 6, the property represents the day of the week when this condition is active.
- `seconds_after_day_start` - the property is used to specify the time after midnight when condition is actually going to be active. For example, it can be active on Monday 2am. In this case `day_of_week` is 1 (Monday) and `seconds_after_day_start` is 7200.
- `duration_minutes` - for how long this condition is going be active. If it's active on Monday 2am until 4am, then `duration_minutes` is 120.

So the record for condition which is active "Monday 2am-4am" looks like:

| ID | day_of_week | seconds_after_day_start | duration_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7200 | 120 |

So now imagine that a user wants to create a new record. I need to check if there is any overlapping conditions. If there is any, we should return IDs of these overlapping conditions so user is aware that condition for the same time already exists.

Examples of two overlapping conditions:

- Monday 2am-4am and Monday 1am-3am.
- Monday 2am-4am and Monday 1am-5am (and vice versa).
- Monday 2am-4am and Monday 3am-5am.
- Monday 2am-4am and Sunday 11pm-Monday 3am

The last example is quite interesting, here is how these records can be represented in DB (but they shouldn't exist, because these conditions are overlapping, and we're trying to avoid that):

| ID | day_of_week | seconds_after_day_start | duration_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7200 | 120 |
| 2 | 0 | 82800 | 240 |

I am trying to make a SQL query with hardcoded values `0`, `82800`, `240` or stored procedure that will accept these three parameters: `day_of_week`, `seconds_after_day_start`, `duration_minutes` and return overlapping IDs from `alert_conditions` table.

I tried to build a query that would look 1 day forward and 1 day back. Forward and back, because data could look like:

| ID | day_of_week | seconds_after_day_start | duration_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 82800 | 240 |
| 2 | 1 | 7200 | 120 |

Where record with ID=1 is legit, but new record with ID=2 should not exist.

So `day_of_week` can be plus/minus something. How would I do that in SQL efficiently?

I created a code that works (and should be valid, not sure about edge cases though) in Ruby, but how do I write similar code in PostgreSQL?

```
require 'ostruct'

def seconds_after_beginning_of_the_week(obj)
  obj.day_of_week * 3600 * 24 + obj.seconds_after_day_start
end

def is_overlapping?(a, b)
  t1_from = seconds_after_beginning_of_the_week(a)
  t2_from = seconds_after_beginning_of_the_week(b)
  
  t1_to = t1_from + a.duration_minutes * 60
  t2_to = t2_from + b.duration_minutes * 60
  
  # In Rails only:
  # (t1_from..t1_to).overlaps?(t2_from..t2_to)
  
  t1_from <= t2_to && t1_to > t2_from
end


# Monday 2am-4am and Monday 1am-3am. - OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 60)
) # => true

# Monday 2am-4am and Monday 4am-6am - NOT OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 14400, duration_minutes: 120)
) # => false

# Monday 2am-4am and Monday 1am-5am - OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 3600, duration_minutes: 240)
) # => true

# vice versa ^^^ - OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 3600, duration_minutes: 240),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120)
) # => true

# Monday 2am-4am and Monday 3am-5am - OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 10800, duration_minutes: 120)
) # => true

# Monday 2am-4am and Tuesday 2am-4am - NOT OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 2, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
) # => false

# Monday 2am-4am and Sunday 11pm-Monday 3am - OVERLAPPING
puts is_overlapping?(
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 1, seconds_after_day_start: 7200, duration_minutes: 120),
    OpenStruct.new(day_of_week: 0, seconds_after_day_start: 82800, duration_minutes: 240)
) # => true
```

Comment: You can use exclusion constraint for the time range plus a condition that the day must be the same.

Comment: Convert values to timestamps and compare like here: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OvbDo9lw). I do not use Postgres, so please forgive me any glitches.